# Help us answer these unanswered questions!

Tags: discussion, support, unanswered-questions

Our "% Answered" stat is currently at 88%, with our Answer Ratio at 1.4. However, it seems as though a lot of our older questions may have answers, and have just not received the attention they need.

Of course, bountying questions or giving them good edits can increase their visibility and maybe get them an answer; but, for someone looking for questions to answer (as today, June 8, is our official "Unanswered Questions Day"), are there any specific questions they should be looking at?

Answer (score 6):

I've compiled a list of questions which I believe can be answered (or improved with new answers) by someone who is an expert in one or more of the series (or tags) the question is related to.

At least half of these questions will not necessarily have sources to cite, so they will rely upon the answerer to be familiar enough with the series to back up his statements.

## Unanswered questions

**Almost definitely have an answer**

I would wager that almost every question on this list can be answered. I haven't seen all the series, so I can't be positive on that. However, these all seem to be related to material (and asked in such a way) that they can be answered either by carefully Googling or by an expert in the series/area addressed.

1. [How much of the original material is animated in first season of Maoyuu Maou Yuusha?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3112/how-much-of-the-original-material-is-animated-in-first-season-of-maoyuu-maou-yuu)
2. [How long was Shi-woon trained by Goomoonryong?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2561/how-long-was-shi-woon-trained-by-goomoonryong)
3. [Is Kafuka Fuura even in the class?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/is-kafuka-fuura-even-in-the-class)
4. [When does Hina learn that her parents died?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3591/when-does-hina-learn-that-her-parents-died)
5. [In which soundtrack album can I find "Virgin Road Ni Hana Ga Saku"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2408/in-which-soundtrack-album-can-i-find-virgin-road-ni-hana-ga-saku)
6. [What was omitted/skipped from the end of Sakamichi no Apollon?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2430/what-was-omitted-skipped-from-the-end-of-sakamichi-no-apollon)
7. [How did GTO: Shonan 14 Days end?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/how-did-gto-shonan-14-days-end)
8. [When does Kud Wafter fit into the story?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/when-does-kud-wafter-fit-into-the-story)
9. [How closely does the La Corda d'Oro manga follow the game?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3990/how-closely-does-the-la-corda-doro-manga-follow-the-game)
10. [How much does the anime differ from the light novels?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/how-much-does-the-anime-differ-from-the-light-novels)
11. [Is Hyouge Mono historically accurate?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/is-hyouge-mono-historically-accurate)
12. [Is 3x3 Eyes based on any real legends?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/is-3x3-eyes-based-on-any-real-legends)
13. [Where is Vampire Knight set?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2787/where-is-vampire-knight-set)
14. [Why did Yukari's father wander off on his honeymoon?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3908/why-did-yukaris-father-wander-off-on-his-honeymoon)
15. [What is the device in the garden in the first episode?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3808/what-is-the-device-in-the-garden-in-the-first-episode)

**Probably have an answer**

These questions seem like they're probably answerable in some form or another. I can't be certain in all cases; these are basically a stretch goal and a list for people who want a challenge answering slightly more obscure questions.

1. [Does "Those Who Hunt Elves" have a definitive ending?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/does-those-who-hunt-elves-have-a-definitive-ending)
2. [What are the stuffed toys in Suguha's room?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/what-are-the-stuffed-toys-in-suguhas-room)
3. [Was Bakuman deliberately made to attract new manga artists in the industry?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3818/was-bakuman-deliberately-made-to-attract-new-manga-artists-in-the-industry)
4. [Why is Poyo completely round?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3453/why-is-poyo-completely-round)
5. [Why does Yokodera idolize Oscar Wilde?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3283/why-does-yokodera-idolize-oscar-wilde)
6. [Did something change for the final episode of Hana Yori Dango?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/118/did-something-change-for-the-final-episode-of-hana-yori-dango)
7. [At the end of the last episode, does everyone retain their old memories?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/at-the-end-of-the-last-episode-does-everyone-retain-their-old-memories)

## Questions that can use better (or more) answers

Our answer ratio is currently sitting at 1.5. However, I don’t know how exactly it’s calculated, so I’m not sure how many answers we really need to improve our stats in that area. There are still some questions that need improvement, though.

1. [Were there any parts of the manga that were skipped in the anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/were-there-any-parts-of-the-manga-that-were-skipped-in-the-anime)
2. [Who is the boy in the coffin in the last episode (of the Gemini of the Meteor)?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3562/who-is-the-boy-in-the-coffin-in-the-last-episode-of-the-gemini-of-the-meteor)
3. [What are the notable differences between Hunter x Hunter in 1999 vs 2011?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3812/what-are-the-notable-differences-between-hunter-x-hunter-in-1999-vs-2011)
4. [Where do the American and Japanese Transformers franchises meet?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/where-do-the-american-and-japanese-transformers-franchises-meet)
5. [How does Pengin die in the fight with Emonzaemon?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3791/how-does-pengin-die-in-the-fight-with-emonzaemon)
6. [Do the Bleach light novels follow the manga plot?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/do-the-bleach-light-novels-follow-the-manga-plot)
7. [Can jutsu be cast across a barrier?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/can-jutsu-be-cast-across-a-barrier)
8. [Can anyone explain the ending of "Koe no Katachi"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3731/can-anyone-explain-the-ending-of-koe-no-katachi)
9. [Is Kiroumaru really a bakenezumi?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/is-kiroumaru-really-a-bakenezumi)
10. [What is the timeline in Vampire Knight?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/what-is-the-timeline-in-vampire-knight)
11. [Why didn't Yokodera send Azuki Azusa back to Okinawa?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/why-didnt-yokodera-send-azuki-azusa-back-to-okinawa)
12. [What is Nara's Strategy?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3951/what-is-naras-strategy)
13. [Did Gon know it was Ponzu who died?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3942/did-gon-know-it-was-ponzu-who-died)
14. [When was Shion's flashback of him and his father camping set at?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/when-was-shions-flashback-of-him-and-his-father-camping-set-at)

Comment: Just a note for later time saving, when you insert a link of the question, it will automatically expand its full name (assuming it's on the same site or meta), so next time you don't have to work hard with the links and names of questions :) Thanks for the list!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I know, but it's limited. It only does the first ten questions or so, then just leaves in the plaintext links. :\

Comment: Huh, didn't know that :o. You learn something new every day.

Comment: "It's okay to answer questions with, "This has not yet been explained," as long as there are sources to back it up" This is a devil's proof; you cannot have a source showing something does not exist lol

Comment: @atlantiza Sources, not as in, "Here is proof it does not exist," but rather, "These are the reasons it likely does not exist." An answer saying "there is no answer" is useless; an answer suggesting *why it is the case* that there is no answer is quite useful.

Comment: @Eric about those 10 links and plaintext afterwards, is this a known bug? Maybe you should post about it on SE meta?