# Help us answer these unanswered questions! Take #2!

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

[The last 'unanswered question' day we had](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/help-us-answer-these-unanswered-questions) was successful enough, but now that we have an even bigger userbase and lots of time to grow our *% Answered* rate has dropped to 87%.

I think that we can bump this back up with a little bit of effort. Here are some things we could look out for:

- We have several [Dangling Id Requests](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/what-should-we-do-about-dangling-id-requests) that sometimes have the answer already in the comments.
- We also have implemented a new [standard for Id Requests](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892) that wasn't around before. Some older questions may need to be closed.
- We also have more people, who might know more than we did before.
- More series (such as [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto)) have ended, so we might be able to answer questions with new information.

After almost half a year, I think we should take a look back at questions we might have missed and see if we can get a little closer to the 90% that we are aiming for.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some queries to find questions you might be able to answer:

- [Based on your  score, askers reputation and how well you do on that particular tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/248702/find-interesting-unanswered-questions)
- [Low Views, High Score](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/249003/low-views-high-votes-yet-unanswered)
- [Most Viewed Unanswered Questions for a tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/223174/the-most-viewed-unanswered-questions-for-a-tag)